# ffmpeg: undefined reference to 'uncompress'

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg, cmake, zlib

i try to cross-compile my program on a 64bit linux for 32bit linuxversion
for other systems it works fine (win, ios, and android but not for linux....)

by 98% there is an error `"undefined reference to 'uncompress'`

only linux make problems... 
i install `zlib1g` and i got the newest version. i want to build it with cmake
here are my **CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS** `-m32 -std=c++11 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasin -fvisibility=hidden -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -lm -lz`

this problem is only with the ffmpeg files (version 2.8) i got the first error with libavformat.a

Comment: When it already starts to compile, your pbolem is probably unrelated to CMake. Please share the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lib you are looking for is `zlib1g-dev` or `zlib-devel`, the development library.